# How to have jquery loop over json data results to create a two column table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my json data response shown in a two column table. I've found lots of posts that show how to show it as a single row, but nothing as a two column table.

This is what I have so far and it is still only showing a single column with multiple rows:

```
    var trHTML = '';

    $.each(data.Titles, function (i, item) {
        var v = 0;


        trHTML += '<tr>';

        if(v <= 2){
            trHTML += '<td><a href="' + data.Links[i] + '">' + data.Titles[i] + '</a><br><img src="' + data.Images[i] + '"></td>';
        }
        else{
            var v = 0;
            trHTML += '</tr>';
            trHTML += '<tr>';
        }

        trHTML += '</tr>';
        v++
    });

    $('#location').append(trHTML);

    },
```

Comment: What are you trying to split into columns? How do you want it to look?  At the risk of sounding condescending, html "columns" are "td" and rows are "tr" ... a 2 column row has the format <tr><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>

Comment: I understand what rows and columns are in html. I want it to tr, td, td, /tr and rinse and repeat.

Comment: Note: you need to get `var v = 0;` out of `$.each(...)`

Comment: Not really, because each time it loops over a new piece of data from the json, it has to set the val to be 0 to count whether td is 1 or 2

Comment: So `v === 0` all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var trHTML = '';
var v = 0;

$.each(data.Titles, function (i, item) {        

    // it keeps v always 0 or 1 regarding if it's first or second column
    if(v >= 2){
        v = 0;
    }

    if(v == 0){
        trHTML += '<tr>';
    }

    trHTML += '<td><a href="' + data.Links[i] + '">' + data.Titles[i] + '</a><br><img src="' + data.Images[i] + '"></td>';

    if(v == 1){
        trHTML += '</tr>';
    }

    v++
});

if(v == 1){
    trHTML += '</tr>';
}

$('#location').append(trHTML);

},
```

Comment: Bingo! Works like a charm. Thanks for chiming in Marek. I appreciate it.